# L'expression « la nuit des temps » comme « symbole d'ignorance et d'obscurantisme » ?

Tags: sens, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Au TLFi on classe l'expression « la [nuit](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nuit/1) des temps » dans une section « par référence à l'obscurité originelle » (B.) et spécifiquement on en dit qu'elle réfère à un « [s]ymbole d'ignorance et d'obscurantisme » (2.) ??

Ce sens concurrence-t-il celui des « [temps reculés](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_nuit_des_temps) » et est-il encore en usage au 21<sup>e</sup> et le cas échéant peut-on en produire une citation ou expliquer de quoi le TLFi parle ici ?

Answer (score 1):

De nos jours, « Depuis la nuit des temps » réfère certainement à un temps très reculé. Mais on peut aussi, en littérature, l'utiliser pour souligner l'ignorance de gens à une époque lointaine :

> Depuis la nuit des temps, ce peuple rend hommage à un être surnaturel.

Au sens littéral, on veut dire :

> Depuis longtemps.

Mais ici, on peut sous-entendre, voire souligner, leur ignorance.

Comment: Renarde, bienvenue sur French SE.  Depuis toujours, oui, mais pourquoi "l'ignorance de gens à une époque lointaine" **et** de nos jours?